# How to split a string and assign as column name for a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe which has a single column like this:

```
  a;d;c;d;e;r;w;e;o
--------------------
0 h;j;r;d;w;f;g;t;r
1 a;f;c;x;d;e;r;t;y
2 b;h;g;t;t;t;y;u;f
3 g;t;u;n;b;v;d;s;e
```

When I split it I am getting like this:

```
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
------------------------------
0 h  j  r  d  w  f  g  t  r
1 a  f  c  x  d  e  r  t  y
2 b  h  g  t  t  t  y  u  f
3 g  t  u  n  b  v  d  s  e
```

I need to assign `a d c d e r w e o` instead of `0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8` as column names.

I tried :

```
df = dataframe
df = df.iloc[:,0].str.split(';')
res = pd.DataFrame(df.columns.tolist())
res = pd.DataFrame(df.values.tolist())
```

I am getting values assigned to each column..But not column headers. What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need create new `DataFrame` by `expand=True` parameter and then assign new columns names:

```
res = df.iloc[:,0].str.split(';', expand=True)
res.columns = df.columns[0].split(';')
print (res)
   a  d  c  d  e  r  w  e  o
0  h  j  r  d  w  f  g  t  r
1  a  f  c  x  d  e  r  t  y
2  b  h  g  t  t  t  y  u  f
3  g  t  u  n  b  v  d  s  e
```

But maybe need `sep=';'` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) if only one column data:

```
res = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';')
```

Comment: I cant add sep=';' in read_csv. because dimension is not fixed

Comment: @qwww - OK, it was only idea :)

Comment: I used the above code. But its giving me length mismatch

Comment: @qwww - It means there is more columns names like df, what return `len(df.iloc[:,0].str.split(';', expand=True).columns)` and `len(df.columns[0].split(';'))` ?

Comment: it gave me 38 and 32

Comment: So there is necessary add new 6 columns values, because missing. Try `res.columns = df.columns[0].split(';').tolist() + ['A','B','C','D','E','F']`

Comment: but i will de boing an usntacking after that. so will this affect that?

Comment: I think it is not problem.